# Unable to install WIne on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine

When I try to install Wine, either through the Ubuntu software center or the terminal, I get this: "package dependencies cannot be resolved". How can I install Wine?

Comment: What "sudo apt-get install wine" shows in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following [Wine HQ's Installation Guide](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

#### Summary

1. Add Wine HQ's Repository

   - `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
2. Update the latest information for apt with the new repo

   - `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install Wine

   - `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

#### Notes

[PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) is a great way to install multiple Wine-dependent applications efficiently and within their own **bottles**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this open the terminal and enter this:

```
 sudo add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

and it might work fine this way.